# Generate Protocol Buffers proto file from bytes intput stream

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, reverse-engineering

I get a .bytes file, it seems to be a kind of protoc ouput of a .proto file

Any idea to use this file in order to encode a message ?

The ways it can be from my view is :

1. by getting a proper .proto file from this .bytes file
2. use the .bytes file as a "proto" file/package to encode the message

Thanks for your help

Comment: By "proto" do you mean [Protocol Buffers?](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto)

Comment: Indeed. Yes it is

Comment: You probably should edit your question and say "Protocol Buffers" instead of proto, especially the question title.  Otherwise many people will not know what you're talking about.

Comment: In fact it's really a ".proto" file that is expected or kind of. 
In protobuf, to encode a message you need to create a proto file with "protoc" application and a .proto file. Then the ouput file in (Java/Python/Ruby/...) will be used in the code to create the message.

Comment: There are two ways I can decipher your question;

1. the contents of the .bytes file is the **compiled schema**, i.e. what you get when using the `--descriptor_set_out` option with `protoc`, or 2. the contents of the .bytes file is a *data payload* (in a particular schema's layout); can you clarify which you mean? (side note: you don't actually "need" to create a proto file, or use protoc, etc; those are just one way of doing things)

Comment: Thx Marc, I tried the first option, I think it's not the right one but not eliminated. About the second, I need to understand how to "import" it in the code (I use Ruby, but not mandatory) in order to generate a message or just see/understand the schema architecture. Which method can be use by Java to get/parse this data/payload ?
It's a reverse-engineering context so I'm not so familiar about protobuf.